# Sugestão de um novo magic link

Tags: debate, novo-recurso, status-pronto, magic-links

Assim como temos o `[ask]` para [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), não seria interessante termos também `[mcve]` (ou algo parecido) para [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Esse é fundamental.

Comment: O mesmo pedido no metão: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240260/add-magic-link-for-mcve

Comment: Não sabia que dava para usar [Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](/help/mcve) só com `[Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](/help/mcve)`, creio que ajude um pouco, mas sem duvida, um *magic link* seria muito melhor =)

Comment: O pedido no MSE ainda não teve resposta. Ele é a nossa melhor chance de conseguir ter isso implementado. *Esperemos*

Comment: Nada ainda (@Gabe)? :) Acabei de testar aqui o magic link que (supostamente) já funciona lá no SOen, mas não funfa. Esse magic link seria mesmo muuuuiiiitooo útil. Qual é a dificuldade?

Comment: Testando [ask] !!! Voila!

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, você fez um teste do `[ask]`, né?

Comment: @Mateus sim, era pra mostrar para o pessoal :) ... esse é um dos melhores atalhos, obrigado!!